# Context depended template argument deduction - type/value mismatch at argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, decltype, typename

Minimal example

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
void function(std::vector<T> vec)
{
    auto tup = std::tuple<decltype(vec)::iterator>(vec.begin());
}

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};

    auto tup = std::tuple<decltype(vec)::iterator>(vec.begin());

    function(vec);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile gives

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ... _Elements> class std::tuple’
auto tup = std::tuple<decltype(vec)::iterator>(vec.begin());
                                              ^
note:   expected a type, got ‘decltype (vec)::iterator’
```

The solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827190/decltypesome-vectorsize-type-doesnt-work-as-template-parameter) suggests adding a `typename`. Placing `typename` in front of the `decltype` in `function` solves the compilation problem. However:

1. Why can the type not be deduced?
2. What is the underlying problem? (Obviously the compiler has doubts about decltype(...)::iterator being a type. But why does it work in `main` but not in `function`?)

Comment: Given that you have tagged C++17 (so CTAD - Class Template Argument Deduction - is available) and that `vec.begin()` is of type `decltype(vec)::iterator`, you can simply write `auto tup = std::tuple{vec.begin()};`. In C++11/C++14 you can use, instead, `std::make_tuple()`: `auto tup = std::make_tuple(vec.begin());`.

Comment: This comment is as valuable to me as the answer itself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `iterator` is a dependent name, you need to use the `typename` keyword to disambiguate it:

```
auto tup = std::tuple<typename decltype(vec)::iterator>(vec.begin());
                  //  ^^^^^^^^
```

Note that `vec` is only a dependent name inside `function`. Inside `main` it's not dependent, and so you don't need to say `typename`.